# Show Stylesheet only on Plugin page WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a lot of CSS scripts in my WordPress plugin which may affect the other WordPress tags, such as `form` as an example:

```
.form {
    padding:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

I can change the CSS, but I want to have a script which only allows the stylesheet to show on the plugin page.

So to clear it up, currently the stylesheet `<link>` is always in the source code of the admin panel, but I want a script which only puts the stylesheet `<link>` in the source code when the user is on the plugin page.

Comment: the better practice would be to add in your body tag a conditional with the pagename or whatever and use `.pagename .form{}` at least then its not another connection for a stylesheet. Dont use php to insert css rules, it can get messy looking for this code to update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_current_screen`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen):

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( $screen->id == 'your_plugin_page' ) ){
    $custom_css = ".form {.....}";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'your_main_style_handle', $custom_css );
}
```

**Update 1:**

To add a submenu to your admin menu:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'your_plugin_admin_menu' );
//Add this to register you styles
add_action( 'admin_init', 'your_plugin_admin_init' );
```

then:

```
/**
 * Register your stylesheet.
 */
function wpdocs_plugin_admin_init() {
    wp_register_style('your-style', plugins_url('scripts/jquery-ui.css',__FILE__ ));

    wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', plugins_url('scripts/jquery-ui.js',__FILE__ ));
}

/**
 * Register your plugin page and hook stylesheet loading.
 */
function your_plugin_admin_menu() {
    $page = add_submenu_page(...., 'your_plugin_manage_menu' );

    //Call 'your_plugin_admin_styles' only on the plugin’s options page
    add_action( "admin_print_styles-{$page}", 'your_plugin_admin_styles');
}

/**
 * Enqueue our stylesheet.
 */
function your_plugin_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('your-style');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');

    $custom_css = ".form {.....}";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'your-style', $custom_css );
}

/**
 * Output our admin page.
 */
function your_plugin_manage_menu() {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: I recommed inline CSS is not good practice of coding but if needed then you can go with this solution, it accurate to work.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work for me; my URL is `options-general.php?page=maintenance`, so `maintenance` should be my ID, and then I wrap `if ( $screen->id == 'maintenance' ) {` around the stylesheet but that removes the style completely.

Comment: Make sure you called `wp_enqueue_style('your_main_style_handle', 'path/to/your/style.css')` before the above code.

Comment: `$screen->id` adds `toplevel_page_` to the menu slug, can you please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create style-sheet, and create hook for that style-sheet reference. Then you can add WordPress using add_action(), within plugin call, where you like to call that script. So it will be referenced at head of page for on specified page as needed. 
Read more on 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/